# iCloud Core Data Syncing Issue - Empty Notifications

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios8, icloud

I'm having some weird issues with iCloud and Core Data syncing across devices. The problem is that records are syncing sporadically and certain notifications are blank.

For example, if I add three records to the database, only two of the three records will sync. Same thing for deletions. However, when I rebuild the data store from scratch (`NSPersistentStoreRebuildFromUbiquitousContentOption`), all the correct entries are present. As you can see in the log file below, I think the issue is that the Notifications are not populating correctly. The middle change should be a deletion but nothing is populated.

See below a copy of the logs and the code I am using for `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`.

Logs:

- 2015-05-02 00:05:42.339 Tracker[1370:219748] persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges
- 2015-05-02 00:05:42.339 Tracker[1370:219748] NSConcreteNotification 0x17485dbe0 {name = com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.importer.didfinishimport; object = ; userInfo = {
  deleted = "{(\n    0xd00000002fe40000 \n)}";
  inserted = "{(\n)}";
  updated = "{(\n)}";
  }}
- 2015-05-02 00:05:42.341 Tracker[1370:219748] Underlying data changed ... refreshing!
- 2015-05-02 00:05:44.293 Tracker[1370:219748] persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges
- 2015-05-02 00:05:44.293 Tracker[1370:219748] NSConcreteNotification 0x170a498a0 {name = com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.importer.didfinishimport; object = ; userInfo = {
  deleted = "{(\n)}"; **[SHOULD BE A DELETION BUT NOTHING]**
  inserted = "{(\n)}";
  updated = "{(\n)}";
  }}
- 2015-05-02 00:05:44.308 Tracker[1370:219748] Underlying data changed ... refreshing!
- 2015-05-02 00:05:46.266 Tracker[1370:219748] persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges
- 2015-05-02 00:05:46.266 Tracker[1370:219748] NSConcreteNotification 0x174a5c0b0 {name = com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.importer.didfinishimport; object = ; userInfo = {
  deleted = "{(\n    0xd00000002fe00000 \n)}";
  inserted = "{(\n)}";
  updated = "{(\n)}";
  }}
- 2015-05-02 00:05:46.292 Tracker[1370:219748] Underlying data changed ... refreshing!

Code:

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[notificationCenter addObserverForName:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                    object:self.persistentStoreCoordinator
                                     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                    NSLog(@"persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges");
                                    NSLog(@"%@", note);

                                    [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                                        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];

                                        NSNotification* refreshNotification =
                                            [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"iCloudReloadTable"
                                                                          object:self
                                                                        userInfo:[note userInfo]];

                                            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:refreshNotification];
                                    }];
                                }];
```

Comment: FYI - I filed a Technical Support Incident with Apple on this. The Apple Engineer sent me sample code, which had the exact same issue present. The Engineer told me to file a bug report, which is still outstanding and unresolved. The only solution I have come up with is not using iCloud and Core Data syncing.

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue. In my case a notification that should contain changes - but does not. None of the notifications on iOS contain details. They do back on macOS. persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges: NSConcreteNotification 0x170c5b150 {name = com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.importer.didfinishimport; object = <NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x170279a00>; userInfo = {
    deleted = "{(\n)}";
    inserted = "{(\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n)}";

Comment: Did anything ever come from your bug report?

Comment: Nothing. I double-checked the bug report I filed on 5/10/15 and the report is still open. As I mentioned, I've abandoned Core Data syncing entirely. I'm now using iCloud Documents syncing instead.

Comment: Dam. Appreciate you looking up the bug report. Thanks Doug.